# Django Monthly Grid / Table

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a stock portfolio with monthly returns. Currently the returns are stored in the database as the first of each month, and the year.
So January 1, 2016 - 5%
February 1, 2016 - 3%

What's the best way to display this in a Django template?
I want to have each year in a separate row, and columns being the dates so:

```
     Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr....
2014
2015
2016
```

What's the best way to put the monthly returns into their correct position?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way, but I end up using a list of tuples for doing this.

In the views.py, make a dictionary entry that contains the line you want to display in a tuple and make a list of those lines:

```
def testview(request):
   x = [(2014,1,2,3),(2015,4,5,6),(2016,7,8,9)]
   return render(request, 'yourtemplate.html', {'data':x})
```

Next make a js table in your template (yourtemplate.html) and loop over the lines

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Jan</th>
    <th>Feb</th>
    <th>Mar</th>
   </tr>

{% for tuple in data %}
   <tr>
      <th>{{tuple.0}}</th>
      <th>{{tuple.1}}</th>
      <th>{{tuple.2}}</th>
      <th>{{tuple.3}}</th>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I hope this helps!